# jQuery Mobile Swipe Event inside containers

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am unable to get a jQuery mobile swipe event to work inside a collapsible set.  I am able to get it to work if I use it outside of the collapsible set.  Test that works:

```
<div id="listitem"> swipe me </div>
```

What I want to work:

```
   <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-mini="true" data-theme=
              "c" data-content-theme="d">
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a">
                  <div>
                    <h4>
                      Conduct Training
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="listitem">
                    <p>
                      <a href="/PlaybookRequest/FileRequest/2014658414/"
                      rel="external" data-ajax="false">link</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
</div>
```

Both are using this javascript on my layout page:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#listitem").swiperight(function () {
            console.log("worked");
        });
    });  
</script>
```

For those curious: I want to be able to have the user click the link to view something and swipe the link for a direct download.

Comment: Is the `#listitem` element in the initial page of your site? If not then it won't be available when the `window.load` fires.

Comment: @twifosp Please post how did you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

When using jQueryMobile you shouldn't be using onload or domready events, but should be using the pageinit event instead:

```
$(document).live('pageinit', function () {
    $("#listitem").swiperight(function () {
        console.log("worked");
    });
});
```

Does that work?

EDIT: changed bind to live.

Comment: I can't get this to work either.  Again it works in my test where I have the elements on the page initially.  But when I create the content divs dynamically as the page is being used, the event is not being bound.

Comment: Ok, change the .bind() to .live() instead. I updated the example to use live instead. This will create this event binding for any dynamically created content.